# How many pictures can i put in my app?

Tags: android, image, heap-memory, gallery, slideshow

I have a gallery working in my app at the moment with about 8 pictures on it. Before i had a bug that use to make it crash because of overload Heap (something like that, not sure).

This was caused by my pictures being too big in file size, so i reduced them it worked. So my main question is How many picture can i actually put in to my app.

I was hoping to have about 5 screens (activities) with some scrolling pictures
I don't want to start changing my app if its just going to crash again

Also does anyone know how to add transitions when scrolling through pictures, for it too look fancy

Comment: regarding your first question you can store the images at server side and access them through your app each time or download them and save them on sdcard, and for your second problem did you checked Viewpager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything depends on the way you manage you pictures. To save the memory (and increase the number of images loaded) you should load a resized picture.

You can subsample picture while loading:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 2;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id, opts);
```

This will load a picture scaled 1/2 of it's original size (keep in mind that subsampling works only for power of 2 values). You can load the picture smaller than the area it will be displayed in and let `ImageView` to upscale it.

If your loaded image is still too large, you can scale it more with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`.

You should be aware that pre-Honeycomb Android doesn't recycle bitmaps like post-Honeycomb Android does. You should call `Bitmap.recycle()` as soon as the bitmap is not used anymore to clear the memory.

For image scrolling you can use `ViewPager`.

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no strict limit on the number of pictures you can include in your app. See the stock Gallery app as an example, I consider myself a relatively light picture taker, but I still have hundreds of images in my Gallery. If you follow the [Bitmap best practices](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) you shouldn't run into any memory issues, and you should be able to include as many images as you want.